# Can I transfer the session value from one browser to another?

Tags: php

I need to transfer the session value in one browser to another browser in my web site

For example from Firefox to Google Chrome

Comment: Do you mean keeping the same session from one browser to another?

Comment: in case of possible in jquery

Comment: Did your try the answer given below. However, it's not PHP

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577052/can-i-migrate-session-data-from-one-browser-to-another-web-development

Comment: What it comes down to is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153943/can-two-different-browser-share-on-cookie - to sum up, the general concensus is "Yes it is theoretically possible using an ugly workaround with Flash, no it is not worth the effort"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set your own cookies with a session id and use a shared session database for all of your domains.  This would require some legwork in implementing your own sessions.

[Cross-Domain Cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342140/cross-domain-cookies)

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to transfer a PHP `$_SESSION` variable or any other value between browsers, even with JS.

If your website contains a login, you could attach information to that login in a database and retrieve it when a user logs in using another browser.